# Web view fragment invoking issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

the app has three activities,the second one is contained 6 Web view fragments with View pager,I don't want to get back to the previous activity when press back button, but just get back one page.I must invoke fragments in the related activity  I know that,I did but can't figure out why the code is not working ,when I go to the second activity  the app crashes ,here is the code. any expert person? thanks

the Web view fragment code.

```
    package com.example.AzaaadCompany.mymessenger;

import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;    
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;    
import android.view.LayoutInflater;    
import android.view.View;    
import android.view.ViewGroup;    
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;    
import android.webkit.WebSettings;    
import android.webkit.WebView;    
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;      

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {    
    public Fragment1() {
        }

    @Nullable       
    @Override    

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        final WebView web = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        web.setInitialScale(228);
        web.loadUrl("http://allrecipes.com/");
        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient1());
        return rootView;
    }

    private class WebViewClient1 extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
           }
       }
```

the activity code

```
package com.example.AzaaadCompany.mymessenger;      

import android.content.Context;    
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.List;

public class secondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener,TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabHost tabHost;

   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        ReplaceFont.replaceDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "birds.ttf");
        manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft= manager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment1 f1= new Fragment1();
        ft.add(R.id.webView,f1);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
       initviewpager();
        initTabHost();

      }
    private void initTabHost() {
        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        String[] tabNames = {"allrecipes", "zoomit", "p30download", "microsoft", "walmart", "amazon"};

        for (int i = 0; i < tabNames.length; i++)    
        {
            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
            tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tabNames[i]);
            tabSpec.setIndicator(tabNames[i]);
            tabSpec.setContent(new FakeContent(getApplicationContext()));
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        }
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int selectedItem) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(selectedItem);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int selectedItem = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedItem);

        HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myscrollview);

        View tabView = tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
        int scrollpos = tabView.getLeft() - (horizontalScrollView.getWidth() - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;

        horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollpos, 0);

           }
    public class FakeContent implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        Context context;

        public FakeContent(Context mcontext) {
            context = mcontext;
        }
        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View fakeView = new View(context);

            fakeView.setMinimumHeight(0);
            fakeView.setMinimumWidth(0);

            return fakeView;
        }
    }
    private void initviewpager() {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        List<Fragment> listFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        listFragments.add(new Fragment1());
        listFragments.add(new Fragment2());
        listFragments.add(new Fragment3());
        listFragments.add(new Fragment4());
        listFragments.add(new Fragment5());
        listFragments.add(new Fragment6());

        MyFragmentPagerAdapter myFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), listFragments);

        viewPager.setAdapter(myFragmentPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add crash log so that any one can find reason easily